# Using SubSurf on Planes to Generate Sharp Edges

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm currently modifying a game ripped 3D model and turning it into EVA foam patterns for cosplay - meaning they need to be "flat", ie. not proper manifold meshes like for 3D printing.

Problem is, on some outer edges, I want to have sharp corners, but have the rest of the geometry smoothed out with Subdivision Surface to get them more rounded. Unfortunately, edge crease doesn't work to make them crisp.
[image]

I could use the other two adjoining edges to get the sharp angles I want, but then I'd be adding creases in the geometry where they should be smooth.

[image]

[image]

Before^

This sort of edge is easier to obtain when extruding it out to make it properly 3D, as the side edges can be creased to get the sharp angle.

[image]

What is the workaround to getting those crisp angles in selected areas around the outside of a plane?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I've never seen this before! Vertex Crease, as demonstrated in this video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djGXnmTTc68

[image]